# Keep order details in arrays?

Tags: arrays, orders, mql4

could you please help me.

1) Is it better to keep orders in the EA's arrays rather than querying the system with the Order.. commands in mql4? Keeping data in arrays means that you have to query the system less and that internet reliability may be less of an issue. However, the coding required to keep an accurate order book is quite cumbersome.

2) How do you keep track of orders that is on the same Symbol but has come from two different EA's?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your needs and ideas, without that it could be quite difficult to tell anything.
you can keep an array of ticket numbers (or `CArrayObj`) but need to check that ticket exists before doing other operations (like trail). if you have problems with internet - change vps and do not try to solve it with coding.
Each ea keeps a book of its own deals.

Cannot imagine sence of keeping just numbers of tickets, but maybe it exists. If you need to store some data in addition to what can be achieved from Order...() then use classes or structures, some fields might be filled with osl,tp,oop,lot,magic, symbol etc once and do not call Order.() functions later except `OrderProfit(),OrderClosePrice() and OrderCloseTime()`-such functions would be called all the time.

Example of how to store data is below: instances of CTrade are added to CArrayObj

```
#include <Object.mqh>
#include <Arrays\ArrayObj.mqh>

class CTrade : public CObject
   {
private:
   int     m_ticketId;
   double  m_oop,m_osl,m_otp,m_lot;//OrderOpenPrice() and sl, tp, lot-add more

public:
           CTrade(const int ticket){
              m_ticketId=ticket; 
           }
  bool     isTicketExist(){
             if(OrderSelect(m_ticketId,SELECT_BY_TICKET))
                   return(OrderCloseTime()==0);
             else return(false);//or GetLastError()!=4108
           }
   };

CArrayObj* listOfTrades=NULL;
int OnInit(void){
    listOfTrades=new CArrayObj;
}
void OnDeinit(const int reason){
   if(CheckPointer(listOfTrades)==POINTER_DYNAMIC)
      delete(listOfTrades);
}

void OnTick(){
   for(int i=listOfTrades.Total()-1;i>=0;i--){
      CTrade *trade=listOfTrades.At(i);
      if(!trade.isTicketExist())
         {listOfTrades.Delete(i);continue;}
      //do trail or what you need
   } // - loop over the array when necessary but clean it first
}

listOfTrades.Add(new CTrade(ticket));// - way to add elements to the list
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this helps a lot.  Could you please explain what you mean with each EA keeps its own orderbook?

Comment: if you have several expert advisors running on different charts - then each ea keeps its own book of trades and do not waste time on other trades, opened by other expert advisors.

Comment: So when you query the orderbook, you only get the orders generated by that EA?  What if you have one EA running across multiple Symbols?

Comment: I think there is no problem with it - keep name of the symbol as a field of CTrade, and call all operations from OnTimer() not from onTick() and that's it