# Mql4 undeclared identifier for delete object

Tags: mql4

I am using the code from the example here [Keep order details in arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561409/keep-order-details-in-arrays)

I am getting an error of `listOfTrades - undeclared identifier` when I add the code in the

```
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//--- destroy timer
   EventKillTimer();

   delete(listOfTrades);

  }
```

I have a feeling it is because `listOfTrades` is declared in the `OnInit()` and not outside global but not sure how that would affect it.

Main.mql

```
#include <CTrade.mqh>

int OnInit()
  {
    CArrayObj *listOfTrades=new CArrayObj;
  }

void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//--- destroy timer
   EventKillTimer();

   delete(listOfTrades);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to declare that globally, before calling `OnInit()`. Missed that point in the mentioned question, will update.

If you pass the object by pointer somehow `void OnTick(){ doSomeFunction(listOfTrades); }` then you should make sure the same variable name is not used (at least in the same file), otherwise you will have warnings that some day may become a bug.

```
void doSomeFunction(CArrayObj* _listOfTrades)// not "listOfTrades" !!! 
  {
   for(int i=_listOfTrades.Total()-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
      CTrade* trade=_listOfTrades.At(i);
      // action with CTrade object
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry when I try to compile with the above function I get the error `CArrayObj - identifier already used` I have search it and looked at the docs but have found nothing similar

Comment: Check that you've imported the class first of all. If that does not help - please show your MCVE.

Comment: ah ok, I had imported the class into the main file and I am working in an include file. Adding to the `listOfTrades.Add(new CTrade(ticket));` didnt give any errors so I thought I was ok having just the reference once. I have added it to the include file and getting no errors now. How do I access the variables though inside the loop. I thought I could `trade.m_ticket` but all I am allowed do is `trade.Next` Thanks

Comment: make it public instead of private, or create better a public getter: `public: int getTicketID()const{return m_ticketId;}`

Comment: of course thanks. Daniel I have summarised what I am try to achieve with storing trade information into an object to be used `onTick()` latter. I have to be able to save the information to a file incase the ea is closed and restarted. I basic have 3 profit targets that I need to store. Any guidance appreciated. Another issue I am still researching is when I do a partial close the broker creates a new ticket. I need to find the new ticket number and then link the tp1, tp2 tp3. That will be a latter challenge.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234536/mql4-save-object-to-array-then-to-file