# mql4 save object to array then to file

Tags: mql4

I have an arrayobject class and I am saving the information when a new record is created or deleted. And then loading the data back when the ea initialises

I an unsure how to create a multi array from the object to save/load file

main.mql4

```
#include <CTrade.mqh>

CArrayObj* listOfTrades=NULL;

int OnInit()
  {
    //initialise listOfTrades and load saved data from file
    listOfTrades = new CArrayObj;

 }
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {

   if(CheckPointer(listOfTrades)==POINTER_DYNAMIC)
      delete(listOfTrades);

  }
void OnTick(){ checkTPHit(listOfTrades); }
```

signal.mql4

```
void Trigger()
  {
         //Create Order
         int newTicket=NewOrder(symbol, order, LotSize, price, takeprofit2, stoploss, comment, 5000);
         if(newTicket>0)
         {
            for(int i=listOfTrades.Total()-1;i>=0;i--){
               CTrade *trade=listOfTrades.At(i);
               if(!trade.isTicketExist())
                  {listOfTrades.Delete(i);continue;}
            }
            listOfTrades.Add(new CTrade(ticket,entry, tp1, tp2, tp3, sl));
            listOfTrades.saveToFile;
            listOfTrades.printTrades;
         } 
}
```

CTrade.mql4

```
#include <Object.mqh>
#include <Arrays\ArrayObj.mqh>

class CTrade : public CObject
   {
private:
   string file = "CTrade.csv"

public:
   int      m_ticketId;
   double   m_entry, m_tp1, m_tp2, m_tp3, m_sl;

           CTrade(const int ticket, entry, tp1, tp2, tp3, sl){
              m_ticketId=ticket;
              m_oop=entry;
              m_tp1=tp1;
              m_tp2=tp2;
              m_tp3=tp3;
              m_sl=sl;
           }
  bool     isTicketExist(){
             if(OrderSelect(m_ticketId,SELECT_BY_TICKET))
                   return(OrderCloseTime()==0);
             else return(false);//or GetLastError()!=4108
           }

           saveToFile (){
            //save data to file everytime add/delete, to load when the ea is initilaized again

            //create multidimensional array and get its size to save to file from objects

            //save to file
             int handle=FileOpen(file,FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN|FILE_COMMON);
             if(handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
               {
                //--- write array data to the end of the file
                FileSeek(handle,0,SEEK_END);
                FileWriteArray(handle,arr,0,arraySize);
                //--- close the file
                FileClose(handle);
               }
             else
                Print("Failed to open the file, error ",GetLastError());            

           }

           loadData () {
            // load data on the ea's initilization
           }

           printTrades(){
            //method to print to terminal while in testing phase
            CArrayObj* _listOfTrades
            for(int i=_listOfTrades.Total()-1;i>=0;i--)
              {
               CTrade* trade=_listOfTrades.At(i);
               // action with CTrade object
               printf(trade.m_ticketId);
              }            
           }
   };
```

Comment: First of all, there are Global Variables in MT4/5. It can be quite convenient in some cases. Another way is to simply use JSON, the two libraries can help. Do not know whether `FileSeek` is used by anyone in the world, rewriting the whole list of open trades does not look to be a big deal in real time. Do you need a JSON example?

Comment: So if I understand you right, probably not. There are global variable that I could store the trade details so when MT4 closes and reopens I can load them again? I did a search and didnt find anything on it. I also looked at writing json to file and dont see anything. Is there anything in particular I should look for? Yes you are right I dont need `FileSeek` for what I am doing. Thanks

Comment: if closing/opening MT4, I would choose json. If you are afraid of MT4 can be closed because light is off, then global variables seems to be the most reliable decision. But it is dirty. A scheduled process to write down the file if something changed, lets say once per minute, might be an internediate solution, I suppose.

Comment: I was planning on saving to file every time a new order is created so just about 5 times a day. I will do a cleanup, then `listofTrades.saveToFile`

Comment: I looked into Global Variables more and they only store single values unfortunately

Comment: yeas, for GV you need to set all the vars one by one. that's why it is dirty

Comment: please check my example for serialization. it should be clear I hope

Answer (score 1):

I use `JAson.mqh` lib for saving data to json - it is simpler. I use json.mqh (prev. messages on SOF if needed, or download from http://lordy.co.nf) for deserialization because the first lib has a bug when parsing arrays (or maybe fixed already, dont know).
If you need a deserialization example, please ask for link in comment

```
#include <JAson.mqh>  //https://www.mql5.com/en/code/13663
class CTrade : public CObject{
   //...

   public:
      static void jsonList(CArrayObj* list, CJAVal &js)
      {
         for(int i=0;i<list.Total();i++)
         {
           CTrade *trade=list.At(i);
           js["array"].Add(trade.json());
         }
      }
      CJAVal         json()const
      {
         CJAVal result;
            result["ticketId"]=(string)m_ticketId;
            result["entry"]=DoubleToString(m_entry,_Digits);
            result["tp1"]=DoubleToString(m_tp1,_Digits);
            result["tp2"]=DoubleToString(m_tp2,_Digits);
            result["tp3"]=DoubleToString(m_tp3,_Digits);
            result["sl"]=DoubleToString(m_sl,_Digits);
         return result;
      }
 };

 void save(CArrayObj* list)
 {
    int handle=FileOpen(generateFileName(InpMagicNumber,_Symbol),FILE_WRITE);
    if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE){Print(__LINE__,__FILE__," error# ",_LastError);return;}
    FileWriteString(handle,CTrade::jsonList(list).Serialize());
    FileClose(handle);
 }
```